# Gatsby: Problem with loading 3rd party scripts

Tags: gatsby, netlify

I'm playing around with this Gatsby Starter: https://github.com/thriveweb/yellowcake/ 
All I did, for now, was trying to add 3rd party scripts like google AdSense to see if it's working.

I've added the Google Adsense code in the snippet injection option in the Netlify settings.

So, the problem is that the banners appear only after I refresh the page. Is there a way to force scripts all the time in Gatsby?

Comment: Any idea how to solve the problem? :D

Answer (score 2):

Install this plugin

```
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet/
```

and then inside of your code you can do this

```
<Helmet>
    <script src="something.com" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</Helmet>
```

Comment: Or you can create a SEO component and store all your meta data inside of it and then call it inside of your html.js

Comment: I had a look at your project, [link](https://github.com/thriveweb/yellowcake/blob/master/src/components/Meta.js) 
You should add your script inside of this component since you already have react helmet installed.

Comment: On line 62 you can add your script. Cheers!

Comment: This is still an issue for me and  I have react helmet, script will not load unless I "land on that page" If going from another page and then navigating to the page the script is on, it will not load.

Comment: @Aquasar I have the same problem, were you able to find a fix for it?